# Import to excel using ods with two decimal places

Tags: sas

I would like my data that is created in SAS to be imported into Excel rounded to two decimal places, I tried with proc export, now by ods excel, but still the numbers have many decimal places. these are my codes

```
proc sql;
    create table COREP_CR_&gv_tbl_date as
    select distinct
    a.DATA_DANYCH as REPORTING_DATE,
    "" as ID,
    sum(a.EXP_PIERWOTNA_NETTO) as  EAD_PRE_CCF format=9.2,
    sum(a.KOREKTA) as  PROVISION format=9.2,
    group by 
    a.EXP_PIERWOTNA_NETTO
    a.KOREKTA
    ;
    quit;
ods excel file="&glb_path2./reports/mth_ak/COREP_CR_&gv_tbl_date..xlsx" 
;
 
proc print data=COREP_CR_&gv_tbl_date; 
run;
 
ods excel close;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions :
Use round()

```
round(sum(a.EXP_PIERWOTNA_NETTO), 0.01)
```